# Setting specific upload directory based on WordPress category?

Tags: php, wordpress, model-view-controller, file-upload, categories

I want to amend my WordPress setup so that when I upload images it automatically uploads them to a sub-folder that matches the category the post or page is sitting under in an 'assets' directory.

The best solution for me would be to be able to choose an upload destination with the ability to create sub-folders in each post or page.

Is this possible? How can I get started?

Answer (score 0):

Try to this

1. Go to admin `Dashboard -> Settings -> Media`
2. And Enter the desired location in Store uploads in this folder
3. And Uncheck Organize my uploads into month- and year-based folders

This is specify the global upload location.
or use use this Plugin [WP Easy Uploader](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-easy-uploader/)

and another Plugin [Uploader](http://wordpress.org/plugins/uploader)